# DFT and FFT application in signal processing

Tags: fft, homework

Can anyone give me some hints to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I cant use any formula for FFT and DFT. and this question has lot of things going on and I am expecting some one to give me some hints on how to start.

Comment: None of the above are decent pitch estimators for piano notes.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to give tips by comments but i don't have the right jet…
on the questions a, c and e you have look to the delta between 2 frequencies.
what is the space between each frequency and how much is the delta frequency of you're sampled time.
Probably questions B,D and f also but i'm not for shure because that a bit more complicated and had never done it myself...

Answer (score 1):

The questions ask, Is it possible to determine the frequency of one tone, and is it possible to distinguish (recognize if there are) two tones?  The only way to see if something is possible is to try it yourself.  You need to use software to generate the various-length tone sequences described in the problem.  Then perform your FFTs and plot the spectral magnitudes of your FFT results.  Inspect the FFT magnitude samples to see if you can determine the frequency of one tone, and distinguish (recognize if there are) two tones. (By sure and try two tones that close to each other frequency in the two-tone case.)